# REGEXP REPLACE teradata to eliminate numeric words appearing in the address field

Tags: teradata, regexp-replace

I want to extract the street name and type from an address field.

```
Input = expected output
3/14 MARKDOWN ST = MARKDOWN ST
22-23 MARKDOWN ST = MARKDOWN ST
33C MARKDOWN ST = MARKDOWN ST
33 MARKDOWN VENUE ST = MARKDOWN ST
44/11 MARKDOWN AVE = MARKDOWN AVE
```

I tried with TRIM(regexp_replace( col, '^[0-9]|[/-]*[0-9]*')) but its only removing the numerics, I want the associated with word numerals to be deleted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`regexp_replace(upper(<your column>),'\b([^A-Z]*\d)\w*','')`

That should replace any words containing non-alpha characters.

Comment: Thanks andrew, the code is almost working, but there are some strings like this "A 8/148 MARKDOWN ST" , "A17/148 MARKDOWN ST" ,"1 AB MARKDOWN RD" for which the output is coming as "A MARKDOWN ST" ,"A17148 MARKDOWN ST", " AB MARKDOWN RD", I just need to extract MARKDOWN as street Name and the remaining as street type. Sometimes strings appear like this as well 
"C/- MARKDOWN + CHAROLTE 309 JANA STREET"

Comment: There is no way a single regex can do what you are looking for. Your last example would probably fail on 3rd party address standardization tools. You've also expanded way beyond your original question (eliminate numeric words).

Answer (score 0):

Should the output for `33 MARKDOWN VENUE ST` be `MARKDOWN VENUE ST`?  If so, try this:

```sql
SELECT 
  myvalue, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(myvalue, '^.*?\s(.*)$') AS mystreet
FROM cte
```

I don't have a `TD` system to test, but give it a try and let me know.  You may need to tinker with the match arguments too.

[DB Fiddle (postgres)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/46636)
[Reference](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/bSkgRmSt8P48II0SKyyH3Q)

Comment: In Teradata, at least, REGEXP_SUBSTR returns the "full match" so `'^.*?\s(.*)$'` would return the original string as long as there was whitespace. But you could use `'.*?\s\K.*'` to return everything after the first whitespace character.

Comment: That CTE clause won't work in Teradata either.  You can't union multiple selects that aren't from a table that way.

Comment: Updated, thanks Andrew.  I need to setup a vm to test these out first.